# creating custom ItemReader with defaultLineMapper using spring annotations

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-batch

I am trying to make a annotation based ItemReader in spring-batch. I was able to make the desired ItemReader in my xml but annotation based is not at all working giving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runScheduler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.Job com.techavalanche.batch.RunScheduler.job; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportJob': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3f9bb1' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'flow'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3f9bb1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#17e6f05' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17e6f05': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#66da50' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#66da50': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'step1' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customItemReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customItemReader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader com.techavalanche.reader.CustomReader.itemReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getFlatFileItemReader' defined in class path resource [com/techavalanche/reader/CustomReader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LineMapper is required
```

and it is caused by :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.Job com.techavalanche.batch.RunScheduler.job; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportJob': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3f9bb1' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'flow'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3f9bb1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#17e6f05' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#17e6f05': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#66da50' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#66da50': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'step1' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customItemReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customItemReader': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader com.techavalanche.reader.CustomReader.itemReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getFlatFileItemReader' defined in class path resource [com/techavalanche/reader/CustomReader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LineMapper is required
```

My CustomReader is

```
package com.techavalanche.reader;

@Component("customReader")
public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<Report> {


    @Autowired
    public FlatFileItemReader<Report> itemReader;

    @Bean 
    public FlatFileItemReader getFlatFileItemReader(){

        return new FlatFileItemReader();
    }


    @Bean
    public DefaultLineMapper getDefaultLineMapper(){

        return new DefaultLineMapper();
    }

    @Autowired
    public DefaultLineMapper<Report> lineMapper;



    @Bean
    public FixedLengthTokenizer getLinetokenizer(){     
        return new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    }
    @Autowired
    public FixedLengthTokenizer linetokenizer;

    @Bean
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper getBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {

        return new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper();
    }


    @Autowired  
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Report> fieldSetMapper;

    public Resource res=new FileSystemResource("D:\\testresource\\report.csv");



    String[] names= {"date","impressions","clicks","earning"};


    @Override
    public Report read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
    NonTransientResourceException {


        for(String name:names){         
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        linetokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"date","impressions","clicks","earning"}); 

        Range range1=new Range(1,12);
        Range range2=new Range(13,15);
        Range range3=new Range(16,20);
        Range range4=new Range(21,28);
        Range[] ranges={range1,range2,range3,range4};

        linetokenizer.setColumns(ranges);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(linetokenizer);     


        fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("report");      
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        itemReader.setResource(res);
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);   


        itemReader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        Report report= itemReader.read();       

        return report;

    }
}
```

My Xml Configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    ">
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.techavalanche" />
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="report" class="com.techavalanche.batch.Report" scope="prototype" />

    <bean id="customWriter" class="com.techavalanche.writer.CustomWriter" />


    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="customItemReader" writer="customWriter"
                    commit-interval="2">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="multiResourceReader"
        class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources" value="file:D:\testresource\report.csv" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="cvsFileItemReader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customItemReader" class="com.techavalanche.reader.CustomReader" />
    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <!-- Read a csv file -->
        <!-- <property name="resource" ref="resource" /> -->

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean id="fixedLengthLineTokenizer"
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="date,impressions,clicks,earning" />
                        <property name="columns" value="1-12,13-15,16-20,21-28" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->
                    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" 
                        /> -->
                    <!-- map to an object -->
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                    </bean>
                </property>

            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: don't mix XML and Java config. Read doc about the desidered configuration type and retry. IMHO your best choice is to move to XML config because it has been already completed

Comment: Thanks Luca for your reply, but I was looking to learn Java config here, If I get able to run this code, my Java config basic would get stronger and it may also help other java batch enthusiast. BTW I have gone through their documentation a couple of time, but still not able to implement the java config way.

Comment: Will be [this official example](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) a good start?